# Testing re-installation - I need a method/program that holds onto files

Tags: testing, installation, wix, filehandle

I'm writing a wix installer and I need to test the reinstall process.  The program that I'm installing has files which can be in use by a second program.

I want to test what will happen if the common files are in use when the re-installation is run.  I'm looking for a program or method that will grab a handle to these common files.  It's a real faff to get a full working environment up and running so I'm looking for a quick method for testing this.

Thanks for any help

Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be open them in an editor (notepad, hex editor etc.). You don't need a special program.

But you don't really need this test. Windows Installer automatically detects this type of files and shows the files in use dialog. This dialog will allow your users to ignore the used files or automatically close the process which uses them.

In the worst case scenario your reinstall process will need a reboot to finish correctly. After a reboot Windows Installer will replace the files automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately allowing a reboot isn't allowed as it's a requirement for there to be no downtime of the second application.  I think in this case I'll need to rename the files, install the new ones, restart the primary program that has been re-installed and finally delete the renamed files.  It's a bit hacky but it'll get the job done.